# Web Services in Siddhi

Tags: web-services, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a web services (REST). I want to call the WS every time an event comes to my stream.

I have to create an extension of Siddhi and call the web service from java?

If I need java to invoke the Web service, should I extend "Aggregate Function" ?.

In Siddhi exists any instruction that I can use to call the web service?

The next is a sample of my WS:

> http://72.37.125.125:3000/phishing?url=www.innerjoin.co

thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to use HTTP event publisher[1] to achieve this OOTB without writing custom code. Using this publisher you can send PUT/POST requests to pre-defined URL with custom payload. Create a HTTP publisher as mentioned in the shared documentation. Then you can use a custom json mapping to create the accepted payload for your web service. When you are creating custom mapping you can refer event attributes inside curly braces as follows.

```
{
   "payload_name_for_webservice":{{attribute_name_in_event}},
}
```

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/HTTP+Event+Publisher

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

but i have a receiver and other publisher.

i want call my WS from siddhi when arrive a new event to "org.wso2.event.sensor.stream:1.0.0", the input parameter to the web service is "meta_sensorName"

how i can make it?

My code is this:

```
/* Enter a unique ExecutionPlan */
@Plan:name('ExecutionPlan')

/* Enter a unique description for ExecutionPlan */
-- @Plan:description('ExecutionPlan')

/* define streams/tables and write queries here ... */

@Import('org.wso2.event.sensor.stream:1.0.0')
define stream sensorStream (meta_timestamp long, meta_isPowerSaverEnabled bool, meta_sensorId int, meta_sensorName string, correlation_longitude double, correlation_latitude double, humidity float, sensorValue double);
```

Comment: Is this input parameter a query parameter or is it in the payload?

Comment: "meta_sensorName", is a payload of org.wso2.event.sensor.stream .

Comment: What I need to know is whether meta_sensorName is query param or payload in your web service call

Comment: "meta_sensorName", is a input parameter for my web services. for example: http://72.37.125.125:3000/phishing?url=<value-meta_sensorName>

Comment: You can't do this Roby. Currently dynamic attributes in the URL is not supported. Dynamic attributes are only supported in payload